# How to stop new tabs popping up

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

My problem is that when my mom searches something up and clicks a link it will then open up a new tab containing the content she just clicked on. She wants it to not add a new tab and just relocate her current tab.

I am using Google Chrome. Everything I searched told me to go to “Search Settings” and then "uncheck a box underneath that". But google chrome does not have that anymore... my mom is very upset by it. any ideas?

Comment: "uncheck a box underneath that" what setting in Google Chrome are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Google

You want to visit [Google Search Settings](https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en&fg=1%20google%20search%20settings) and scroll down until you see **"Where results open"** and check to see that **"Open each selected result in a new browser window"** isn't checked.

## Yahoo

For yahoo, you want to visit the [Yahoo Search Preferences](https://search.yahoo.com/preferences/preferences;_ylt=A0LEVxIKoZJY8t4AjfdXNyoA%20Yahoo%20Search%20Preferences) and then next to **"Open search results"** set it to "in current tab".

---

If your using a different search engine than these tell me so I can get the correct info for you

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your problem is or what you are trying to achieve.

However you can find chromes search settings as a section in the general settings page. Click on `Settings` in the menu or type `chrome://settings/` in the address bar. There you can configure which search engine is used for stuff that you type in the address bar.